# Deserializing XML Over Tcp connection

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am running a server on a host machine and a client off my computer. I'm serializing the xml I want to send and send it to the server over a TCP connection. On the server, I receive the xml and try to deserialize it. However, I get this error:

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 1).
```

I looked at the exception and I got this as an inner exception:

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

Client code to serialize and send xml:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BalanceInquiryReqType));
BalanceInquiryReqType req = new BalanceInquiryReqType();
req.loyaltyToken = "416600000003";
req.storeID = 400020;
req.transactionDateTime = DateTime.Now;
req.transactionID = "123";
using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(send))
{
    xs.Serialize(writer, req);
}
```

Server code to deserialize xml:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
int bytesread = handler.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
String received = BitConverter.ToString(buffer);    
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BalanceInquiryReqType));
BalanceInquiryReqType request = new BalanceInquiryReqType(); 
using (TextReader txt = new StringReader(received))
{
    request = (TransReqType)xs.Deserialize(txt);
}
```

The xml I sent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <BalanceInquiryReqType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
        <loyaltyToken>416600000003</loyaltyToken>
        <storeID>400020</storeID>
        <transactionDateTime>2014-01-15T14:40:02.4960937-05:00</transactionDateTime>
        <transactionID>123</transactionID>
   </BalanceInquiryReqType>
```

The schema of the xml I sent:

```
<xs:complexType name="BalanceInquiryReqType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="TransReqType" />
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

The base extension:

```
<xs:complexType name="TransReqType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="loyaltyToken" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="storeID" type="xs:long" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="transactionDateTime" type="xs:dateTime" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="transactionID" type="xs:string" />  
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="cashierID" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="stan" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="terminalID" type="xs:string" />
</xs:sequence></xs:complexType>
```

Anybody have any ideas what it could be? I've tried variations of readers, like using a MemoryStream, but I kept running into random various issues.

Comment: Well, write the XML received by the server into a file and look at it. What do you see? (Don't look on the XML you sent, but look at the XML your server received!)

Comment: Just debug your code. At least put a Debug.Write here `String received = BitConverter.ToString(buffer);` And read the docs about *BitConverter.ToString* . `received` **is not** an xml.

Comment: How do you write the XML document to the socket? I suppose, `send`is a StringBuilder; if not, what type is it? Have you tried to use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)` (or another Encoding) instead of `BitConverter.GetString(buffer)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Text.Encoding to pick an Encoding and use that instead of BitConverter.  It's what you want here.  Then call GetBytes on the client and GetString on the server.